# Building SQL Server query based on user selections

Tags: sql-server

I have a small application which will access an alarm log DB and a form which has optional filters that can be selected by the user. With no filters selected, the query to pull records is

```
strCommandText = "SELECT [Alarm Number], Device, Description, Severity, CauseMnemonic, [Start Time], [End Time]," _
                & "Zone, Category, [Downtime Flag], Duration FROM Alarmlog"
```

If any of the filter check boxes are checked, and the matching field has a value, I would like to add it into the query as a parameter. I have this working for one or another filter - but not multiple filters applied.

```
If bFilterAlarmNumber Or bFilterCategory Or bFilterCause Or bFilterDate _
                Or bFilterDate Or bFilterDescription Or bFilterDevice Or bFilterDowntime _
                Or bFilterSeverity Then
                    strCommandText = strCommandText + " WHERE "
                End If
                If bFilterAlarmNumber Then
                    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AlarmNumber", strAlarmNumber)
                    strCommandText = strCommandText & " [Alarm Number] LIKE '%' + @AlarmNumber + '%'"
                End If
                If bFilterCategory Then
                    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", strCategory)
                    strCommandText = strCommandText & " Category LIKE '%' + @Category + '%'"
                End If
                Command.CommandText = strCommandText
```

I realize that I need to add an "AND" in between my parameters, but my question is - can someone recommend a way to do this? If any one of the filters is the only one checked, the AND would not apply. I am doing something similar for the inclusion of the WHERE clause, but I think this is a little more complicated.

Thank you

Comment: A common hack is to include `WHERE 1 = 1` in the static query and then unconditionally append ` AND ...` for each selected filter.

Comment: That did the trick! TYVM

Comment: You might also check out this article which discusses this type of query. http://www.sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/ I would suggest moving this to a stored procedure instead of building up your sql in your application.